# Recording and uploading audio from javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, web-mediarecorder

I am trying to record *and upload* audio from javascript. I can successfullly record audio `Blob`s from a `MediaRecorder`. My understanding is that after recording several chunks into blobs, I would concatenate them as a `new Blob(audioBlobs)` and upload that. Unfortunately, the result on the server-side keeps being more or less gibberish. I'm currently running a localhost connection, so converting to uncompressed WAV isn't a problem (might be come one later, but that's a separate issue). Here is what I have so far

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
.then(stream => {
  const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  mediaRecorder.start(1000);
  const audioChunks = [];

  mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
    audioChunks.push(event.data);
  });
  
  function sendData () {
    const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
    session.call('my.app.method', [XXXXXX see below XXXXXX])
  }
})
```

The `session` object here is an `autobahn.js` websockets connection to a python server (using `soundfile`. I tried a number of arguments in the place that was labelled by `XXXXX` in the code.

1. Just pass the `audioBlob`. In that case, the python side just receives an empty dictionary.
2. Pass `audioBlob.text()` in that case, I get something that looks somewhat binary (starts with OggS), but it can't be decoded.
3. Pass `audioBlob.arrayBuffer()`. In that case the python side receives an empty dictionary.

A possible solution could be to convert the data to WAV on the serverside (just changing the mime-type on the blob doesn't work) or to find a way to interpret the `.text()` output on the server side.

Comment: remove python from a tag.

Comment: I agree that this is borderline "python" and removed the tag. However, by downvoting the question, you also indicate that the question is insufficiently researched, unclear or not useful. What information is missing? What could I change to make it more useful? Thanks!

Comment: Send it as `FormData` and read as a file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use [recorder.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recorderjs) and then use the `getBuffer` method in there to get the wave data as a `Float32Array`.